# how to configure run configuration of pydev google appengine project in eclipse ?

Tags: django, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I'm trying to run django on top of Google appengine. but finally i could not find 
why it cannot be done..

I follow the manual of 2 websites and finally could not solve my problem..

```
 << References >>
 1. [mkyong.com][1]
 2. http://andablue.blogspot.kr/2013/03/google-app-engine-python-django-google_9.html
```

Below image is the description of structure of project.

[image]

I configured pydev google appengine run configuration like below.

[image]

[image]

But when i try to run it i confront the error message like below ..

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '?/Users/nextdoordoctor/dev/ndd_mobile/src?'

How should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would really wanna suggest you to use [django-deployer](https://github.com/natea/django-deployer) because it makes life essay as it deploys any Django app to the following PaaS providers: Dotcloud, Stackato, OpenShift and Google App Engine. The goal of django-deployer is to minimize the effort to deploy a Django app to any of the popular PaaS providers

Also have a look on its [demonstration](http://appsembler.com/blog/deploy-django-apps-to-google-app-engine-with-django-deployer-in-5-minutes/).